# Converting javaScript to typeScript and how to import that file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to convert js file into ts. But upon returning config from the constructor throws error. Is this the right way I'm converting js->ts. Also how do I change the import statement as well. PFB my code:

This is the original js file and is being imported as

```
let caasConfig = require('../config/caasConfig.js')(process.env.NODE_ENV);
//////////////////// caasConfig.js//////////
module.exports = function getConfig(environment) {
  let config = {
    defaultContentPath: 'default/project/Us',
    urgentContentPath: 'urgent/project/R',
    defaultContentId: 'default',
    urgentContentIdSuf: 'urgentcontent',
    contactInfo: 'contactinfo/project/CCD',
    contactInfoSele: 'contactinfoselection/project/RC'
  };

  if (environment === 'local' || environment === 'development') {
    config.domainPath =
      'https://xyz/rs/cf//rest/public/content/pageid/';
  } else {
    config.domainPath =
      'https://xyz/rs/cf/content-adapter-webservice-production-current/';
  }
  return config;
};
```

**caaSConfig.ts**: (the way I'm converting)

```
export class getConfig {
  environment: any;
  constructor(environment) {}
  if (environment === 'local' || environment === 'development') {
    config.domainPath =
      'https://xyz/rs/cf//rest/public/content/pageid/';
  } else {
    config.domainPath =
      'https://xyz/rs/cf/content-adapter-webservice-production-current/';
  }
  return config;
};
}
config = {
  defaultContentPath: 'default/project/Us',
  urgentContentPath: 'urgent/project/R',
  defaultContentId: 'default',
  urgentContentIdSuf: 'urgentcontent',
  contactInfo: 'contactinfo/project/CCD',
  contactInfoSele: 'contactinfoselection/project/RC'
};


// the way I'm importing this in another file: 

import {caasConfig}(process.env.NODE_ENV) from '../config/caasConfig';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're rewriting it then just export the function as a named export.

```
export function getConfig(environment: string) {
  const config = {
    defaultContentPath: 'default/project/Us',
    urgentContentPath: 'urgent/project/R',
    defaultContentId: 'default',
    urgentContentIdSuf: 'urgentcontent',
    contactInfo: 'contactinfo/project/CCD',
    contactInfoSele: 'contactinfoselection/project/RC'
  };
  if (environment === 'local' || environment === 'development') {
    config.domainPath =
    'https://xyz/rs/cf//rest/public/content/pageid/';
  } else {
    config.domainPath =
      'https://xyz/rs/cf/content-adapter-webservice-production-current/';
  }
  return config;
};
```

Then you can use it like...

```
import { getConfig } from '../config/caasConfig';
```

EDIT:

It may help others if you define a type for the return:

```
export interface Config {
  defaultContentPath: string;
  urgentContentPath: string;
  defaultContentId: string;
  urgentContentIdSuf: string;
  contactInfo: string;
  contactInfoSele: string;
  domainPath: string;
}
```

Then update your function to:

```
export function getConfig(environment: string): Config {
```

This way when you're using it you could do something like...

```
import { getConfig, Config } from '../config/caasConfig';

class SomeClass {
  private config: Config;

  constructor() {
    this.config = getConfig('development');
  }
}
```

Comment: This way, it gives this error: Property 'domainPath' does not exist on type '{ defaultContentPath: string; urgentContentPath: string; defaultContentIdSuffix: string; urgentContentIdSuffix: string; contactInfoPath: string; contactInfoSelectionPath: string; }'.

Comment: Probably easiest to just add `domainPath: ''` when you initially setup the `config` object.  TS hasn't been too friendly to me when I try and create an object with some of the required fields and then add the rest in later. I assume there is some fancy way to do this I'm just missing.

Comment: Or you could calculate `domainPath` before you construct `config` so you have the value.